# Is there an equivalent of a .pkpass file for Google Wallet Items?

Tags: android-pay

Apple's Passbook uses .pkpass files to encapsulate the item. These are easily transferable by many mediums (email, mms, etc).

Does Google provide an equivalent package / file for Google Wallet Items?

Comment: From what I'm reading, the pkpass is unique (for now) to passbook/passkit as apple wanted an edge into Android market so they've made the payment method data portable across mobile platforms. It was likely a costly undertaking to create a safe but usable storage format, so I'd bet Google won't invest the same effort until either an open standard is defined it they decide to have Google wallet for iOS

Comment: @Anthony, please reply with an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Mr. @orangechicken did you find solution of this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no equivalent of a .pkpass *file* for Google Wallet Items. Google Wallet Items are managed online by the Google Wallet system. The impact of this is that there's no *thing* — besides a link — that can be shared by email or MMS. This is good for managing duplication, perhaps, but (slightly) limits distribution channels to web only.